# Dropdown menu missing last row inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and dropdown menus, my query works, but when displaying it is always missing the last row entered.  So if I have two rows entered, the drop down will only display one?  What am I doing wrong?

```
     <?php
       require("********");

      $query=mysql_query("select * from types");

        echo "<table  >
          <tr align='left'>
          <th><font color='red'>Description</th>
          </tr>";

          $options='';

          while($dbfield = mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
            $options .= '<option>'.$dbfield['Description'].'</option>';
            echo "
              <form method='post'>
          <td><select name='Description'><? echo $options; ?></select>
          </tr>";
```

Comment: You are building invalid html and have invalid PHP. You cannot embed php code blocks inside php code blocks. `<?php echo "<?php echo 'foo' ?>" ?>` is not going to echo `foo`, it's going to echo raw php code.

Comment: Im an idiot new comer...This resolved it..thanks

$options
   
   
<td><select name='Description'>
  
  
<$options></select

Answer (score 1):

- You don't close (`}`) your `while` loop.
- You're also not consistent
  with your table structure.
- `mysql_` functions are also deprecated.

  ```
  <?php

  require("********");

  $query=mysql_query("select * from types");

  echo "<form method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr align='left'>
  <th><font color='red'>Description</th>
  </tr>";

  $options='';

  while($dbfield = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      $options .= '<option>'.$dbfield['Description'].'</option>';
  }

  echo "<tr>
  <td><select name='Description'><? echo $options; ?></select>
  </tr>";
  ```